# navigating filesystem in vim -> :find vs. :edit

Tags: vim

When opening files in Vim I almost always do something like this:

```
:e subDir/**/file<ctrl-d>
```

But in the docs and basically every StackOverflow/blog post I have read it seems that people use "find" the way I use "edit".

What am I missing by using the edit command instead of the find command?

Comment: `find` search the `'path'` in vim. Whereas `:edit` only takes the current working directory as the root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:edit` is restricted by default to the working directory: if you need to edit a file that is not under your working directory you will have to provide its absolute path or a path relative to the working directory. Also, you need to provide the necessary globs.

`:find` is superficially very similar to `:edit` but the (big) difference is that it finds files in the directories specified in the `path` option. `path` is what makes `:find` a lot more interesting than `:edit`.

With `set path=,,` you essentially get the same behavior as `:e foo`.

With `set path=**` you essentially get the same behavior as `:e **/foo` except you don't have to use any glob.

With `set path=.,**` you also get access to files in the same directory as the current file.

With `set path=.,**,/path/to/some/central/vendor/directory` you also get access to files from that directory… and so on.

Comment: It may be worth noting that adding `**` to `'path'` is not really how `'path'` was intended to be used. The purpose of `'path'` is to point to the roots of your "included" code (say Python modules, Java source dependencies, Vim plugin bundles, etc.). Then `:find` is very much like `:edit`, only that it uses multiple search directory roots, instead of just the working directory.