# VIM command + p like command for finding files

Tags: vim

I recently switched to vim from VSCode.

In VS Code I can do a fuzzy search by typing ctrl + p and typing in a file.
In VIM how do I search for files by fuzzy searching just the name.

Comment: FWIW, Max Cantor makes some nice recommendations about how to configure Vim to leverage seeded functionality to perform fuzzy file searches here, https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/57ps0k/how_to_do_90_of_what_plugins_do_with_just_vim/

Answer (score 9):

You can install a fuzzy file search tool such as [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).
FZF also has a Vim plugin, allowing you to do `:FZF` to fuzzy search.

Without plugins or external tools, you can search files with `:e[dit]` if you open vim in the project root directory. It's not really fuzzy search though.
Do `:e **/StartOfFileName` `<tab>` or e.g. `:e **/*.ts` `<tab>` to list all typescript files.

You could also use `:find`, which is similar to `:e[dit]` but allows some interesting options by tweaking `path`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32901108/10374042).